# How to set custom HTTP URL prefix with wsadmin Jython script

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

I want to write a jython-script that sets Enterprise Application Parameters after deployment.
Especially change the "HTTP endpoint URL Information" for an ear-file.
In Websphere admin-console I do this by selecting
Applications > WebSphere Enterprise applications > [Enterprise Application] > Provide HTTP endpoint URL information >  Select default HTTP URL prefix
Select custom HTTP URL prefix

Is it possible to do this step after deployment per wsadmin-script?

Answer (score 0):

Check this page - [Working with web services endpoint URL fragment property files](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/txml_wbs_endptURL_prop.html) - it is possible to configure it via wsadmin using prepared property file.